# What can I do to make my downstairs layout better?

Tags: layout

[image]

Hi. Looking to modify our downstairs since the house isn't selling and it doesn't work in its current state. We've had a structural engineer out so load bearing walls have been identified. What would your suggestions be? Things being considered :

Move kitchen into lounge and rejig dining room and current kitchen to make a utility room between bathroom and rest of downstairs

Knocking through dining room and kitchen to make a big kitchen diner

Adding an extension to square off the house (last resort as have two kids under 2.5).

Any thoughts or other suggestions? Any feedback on how tricky it is to change kitchen to front of house? Boiler is in the bathroom and no upstairs loo if that is useful info.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Welcome to DIY.stackexchange.com. As with all stack exchange sites, this is a Q&A site, not a discussion forum. As such we need a specific question to answer. And, in my opinion, you've given all the answers in your question anyway, so I'm not sure what we can provide, other than opinion on which is best. And opinion is more of a Discussion topic than a Q&A one, hence I'm not sure your question as currently worded is a great fit. Your side question is answerable here, but as a separate question: "What would be required to move the kitchen in this house?"

Answer (score 2):

Moving the kitchen to another location is typically a rather large project because things like plumbing and critical electrical wiring have to move. Even swapping sides in a kitchen can lead to a lot of "down to the framing" type of work.

Your picture does not show the current kitchen layout so it is not possible to envision just what may be possible. Despite that, opening up the space between the kitchen and dining room may be the easiest thing to solve the long narrow kitchen plan as shown.

Comment: i agree, open up that kitchen and dining room